# Why didn't Mello see Shinigami after touching the Death Note in Episode 29?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-note

In the 29th episode of [**Death Note**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0877057/) ([**Father**](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Father)), a third Shinigami ([**Sidoh**](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Sidoh)) arrived on  Los angels to get his notebook back.

He needed the current owner,(*which was one of the Mello's subordinate, **Jack Neylon***) to touch the death note in order to see him.

How did [Jack Neylon](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Jack_Neylon) become the owner of the note if he didn't touch it?

And when Sidoh arrived the death note was in the hands of Mello, but he didn't see Sidoh, why is that?